# How do I write a function that changes the structure and replaces values?

Tags: r, function, numeric, gsub

There are some structural issues with my dataset, I am trying to write a function, named 'convert_number' that will accomplish the following:
 - change the numbers in a column so that the ',' is a '.'
 - convert that column to a double
The function should also be able to call different columns as there are about 10 I want to change.

I have a few ideas but none of them are working. I want some fresh brains on this, anyone have any suggestions? Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `as.numeric(sub(",", ".", df1$colnm))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following,

```
f1 <- function(x){
    x1 <- as.numeric(sub(',', '.', x))
    return(x1)
    }
```

You can then apply it to any column, i.e.

```
df[your_cols] <- lapply(df[your_cols], f1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are interested in converting the columns to numeric after changing the `,` to `.`, one option is

```
colsofinterest <- names(df1)[1:10]
df1[colsofinterest] <- lapply(df1[colsofinterest], function(x) 
           as.numeric(sub(",", ".", x)))
```

More easier option is while reading the dataset, specify the `dec`, and it would automatically change the type to double

```
df1 <- read.csv('file.csv', dec = ",")
```

Or in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate_at(vars(colsofinterest), ~ as.numeric(str_replace(., ",", ".")))
```